# Micrometer - Add default prefix in metric name

Tags: micrometer

In micrometer, we can create a new gauge doing something like

```
myMeterRegistry.gauge("my_metric", 69);
```

See the code here https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/MeterRegistry.java#L468

Would be possible to include a "prefix" name by default for my `myMeterRegistry` object?

Manually, it should like:

```
myeterRegistry.gauge("myprefix_my_metric", 69);
```

My goal is that every developer that creates a gauge metric in my application does not have to take care of adding the "myprefix_" at the beginning of the metric name

Answer (score 11):

A [MeterFilter](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_meter_filters#_transforming_metrics) would let you do that (but don't!):

```
new MeterFilter() {
    @Override
    public Meter.Id map(Meter.Id id) {
      return id.withName("myprefix." + id.getName());
    }
}
```

However a common prefix is typically a smell of an incorrect dimensionality. Usually users try to add a region, host, or the application's name as a prefix. Those are better provided as tags since then you can aggregate across systems and use common dashboards.

The `commonTags` approach is recommended:

```
registry.config().commonTags("team", "myteam", "region", "us-east-1");
```

For hierarchical meter registries, tags will be included in the name as a prefix.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Question, using the common tags, the developer should care about add that common tags, right? I mean, there is not a way to do that via configuration at project level, so any MeterRegistry object used in the project will get those common tags by default, right?

Comment: It appears you can do this via configuration (see https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/646) if you are using SpringBoot.  Also some backends like Prometheus allow for this as part of the service discovery mechanism (see https://prometheus.io/blog/2015/06/01/advanced-service-discovery/)

Comment: this is how it can be done with spring bean https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html 
-----
@Bean
MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
 return registry -> registry.config().commonTags("region", "us-east-1");
}

Comment: @checketts, would you disagree with the prometheus metrics naming best practice, or is there a nuance here you would clarify?
https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/ "For metrics specific to an application, the prefix is usually the application name itself."

Comment: @LaFayette Happy to clarify. If my app processes orders then I would name my metric with my app: `myapp.orders.processed.total` (but not based on the region it is deployed, since that would be a tag to aggregate your orders across app deployments). The MeterFilter is used when trying to alter an existing meter (like provided by a library) like `cache.hits`, don't prefix that meter, since caching isn't unique to your app. (Perhaps a new question is warranted if you need more details)

Comment: Hey @checketts, this question pops up as first google search result for adding a prefix to metric names. I knew I wanted to add such prefix or `namespace` as refered to in the terminology used in prometheus's nameing convetion linked by @LaFayette (Fred), since I've had seen it before, I just wanted to see if there is a possibility to do so using `.config()`, but then I was hit by your answer. Thankfully your last comment clarifyed it. It would be very helpful for future searchers if you could just add some details to this answer without the need for a new question. Thanks!

Comment: @A4L I think the `MeterFilter` used in the answer is the way to go for non-hierarchical registries. Perhaps a separate question specific to the registry you are using would be useful.